# Trying to convert an xsl file and an xml file to html and then display that in a WebBrowser object

Tags: c#, .net, html, browser, xslt

So I am trying to convert a xml file that uses an xsl file then convert both of those to html which I can bind to a WebBrowser object. Here is what I have so far that isnt working:

```
        protected string ConvertXSLAndXMLToHTML(string xmlSource, string xslSource)
        {

        string resultDoc = Application.StartupPath + @"\result.html";
        string htmlToPost;


        try
        {
            XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlSource);
            XslTransform myXslTrans = new XslTransform();

            //load the Xsl 
            myXslTrans.Load(xslSource);

            //create the output stream
            XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(resultDoc, null);

            //do the actual transform of Xml
            myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);

            myWriter.Close();

            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(resultDoc);
            htmlToPost = stream.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Close();

            File.Delete(resultDoc);

            return (htmlToPost);


         }

         catch (FileNotFoundException fileEx)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("File Not Found: " + fileEx.FileName, "File Not Found Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("General Exception: " + ex.Message, "Exception Thrown" , MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

This code is in a function that returns htmlToPost and the returning data is bound to the WebBrowser like this:

```
            // webReport is the WebBrowser object
            // htmlString is the html passed to the function
            // that will bind the html text to the WebBrowser object

            webReport.Navigate("about:blank");
            IHTMLDocument2 test = (IHTMLDocument2)webReport.Document.DomDocument;
            test.write(htmlString);
            webReport.Document.Write(string.Empty);
            webReport.DocumentText = htmlString;
```

I know that XslTransform has been deprecated but all the examples online use it so thats why I am using it.

The error i get is this :

A Runtime Error has occured. Do you wish to debug?

Line: 177
Error: Expected ')'

It happens when this code tries to execute:

```
        IHTMLDocument2 test = (IHTMLDocument2)webReport.Document.DomDocument;
        test.write(htmlString);  //this is the actual line that causes the error and it traces into assembly code.
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

EDIT #1: If i hit no to debugging the errors the page shows as i would like.

Comment: Might be an issue with the validity of the XML or XSL itself

Comment: If I hit no to the errors, the content displays correctly. Is there a way to suppress the errors?

Answer (score -1):

I do this in my project

Make a temp file:

```
string ReportTempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "pubreport" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".html");
```

Save the content:

```
var root =
                new XElement(ns + "html",
                    new XElement(ns + "head",
                        new XElement(ns + "title", "Publisher Report"),
```

// ...

```
var docType = new XDocumentType("html",
              "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN",
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd", null);

    var doc =
        new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no"),
            docType,
            root
        );

    doc.Save(path);
```

Then pass a MemoryStream to the webbrowser control.

```
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(ReportTempPath));
```

Comment: My implementation works, im looking for the type of bug im getting to be addressed.